# Sikuli IDE or Eclipse/JAVA for windows based application?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, qa-developer, sikuli, testing-framework

I am trying to prepare a POC using Sikuli. Can any one suggest me what is the best approach to use Sikuli for a windows based application ? Should I use Java with Eclipse or the Sikuli IDE itself?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I've used Sikuli, I concluded the following: Sikuli IDE's one (and almost only) benefit was that it interpreted image paths as images allowing for a nicely looking code mixed with actual images. The IDE though missed a lot of features other IDEs offer from out of the box.

[How to use Sikuli together with other IDE’s](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/040-other-ide.html) documentation page mentions NetBeans and Eclipse, but I would first try [Intellij IDEA IDE from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is using sikuli with any programming language.

**Benifits**

- learning sikuli is not difficult (To run basic sikuli programme you need to learn only a few methods like click, find)
- You can learn more about sikuli and java when you coding sikuli with any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there is much of a difference for a proof of concept.  The IDE might be easier to set up.  But the IDE would be limited if you decided to move forward using Sikuli.  A full featured programming IDE, like Eclipse, or intellij, would give you the benefit of static code analysis, auto-completion, debugging capabilities, version control tools, plugins, dependency management, etc.

All of these would be desirable if you end up integrating Sikuli with other automation frameworks or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> ...for **windows** based application?

Sikuli was already mentioned. Just to add another option: For screenshot-based **Windows** desktop automation there is also [SeeShell](https://a9t9.com/). Unlike Sikuli, it is not cross-platform, but optimized for Windows which brings a deeper platform integration. So if one only needs to work on Windows, it can be a good option.